# What's the proper type declaration of React context functions to avoid linting issues?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint, use-context

I am using React Context and I have:

```
const DocumentContext = createContext<
    [DocumentStateType, React.Dispatch<any>, React.Dispatch<any>]
>([initVal, () => { }, () => { }]);
```

But my linter complains:

```
Unexpected empty arrow function @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
```

I know I can turn that off in my linting settings, but is there a right way to do it?

Comment: `() => undefined`? It's the same as `() => {}`, but the body is not empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking only to suppress linter message you may declare it as:

```ts
const DocumentContext = createContext<
    [DocumentStateType, React.Dispatch<any>, React.Dispatch<any>]
>([initVal, () => { /* do nothing */ }, () => { /* do nothing */ }]);
```

or as:

```ts
const DocumentContext = createContext<
    [DocumentStateType, React.Dispatch<any>, React.Dispatch<any>]
>([initVal, () => undefined, () => undefined]);
```

If you're absolutely sure you're not going to use this default value anywhere. i.e you don't have components using this context beyond this context's provider you may simply define it as:

```ts
const DocumentContext = createContext<
    [DocumentStateType, React.Dispatch<any>, React.Dispatch<any>]
>(null as any);
```

Comment: The third option complains about the `any`

Comment: You may replace it with 'unknown'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the option `allowArrowFunctions`

[Documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-empty-function#allow-arrowfunctions)

```
"@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": ["error", {"allow": ["arrowFunctions"]}],
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly what the OP said they already know they can do?

Comment: I thought he was saying more on the lines of "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "off"

Comment: The direct question was "what is the proper type declaration...". So I doubt they're looking for eslint workarounds, but I guess that's up to the OP to decide.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [lodash](https://lodash.com/) you can use the [`noop`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.noop) function to bypass linting.

*I assume other libraries have similar functions.*